# Py script not running properly on Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bioinformatics, pyscript

I have the following files:

```
SRR15013283_1.fastq  SRR15013283_2.fastq  SRR15013284_1.fastq  SRR15013284_2.fastq
```

I was trying to run my python script name `trimScript_Denovo.py` but keeps returning blank, not running.
My script is this

```
import sys
import os

baseCommand = "java -jar /home/user/sra_data/Trimmomatic-0.39/trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -phred33"
baseParamter = "ILLUMINACLIP:/home/user/sra_data/Trimmomatic-0.39/adapters/TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:
3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36"
fileBaseName = "SRR"
extName = ".fastq"



for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
    accessionName = sys.argv[i]

    inputFile1 = fileBaseName + accessionName + "_1" + extName
    inputFile2 = fileBaseName + accessionName + "_2" + extName

    outputPFile1 = fileBaseName + accessionName + "_1_P" + extName
    outputUPFile1 = fileBaseName + accessionName + "_1_UP" + extName
    outputPFile2 = fileBaseName + accessionName + "_2_P" + extName
    outputUPFile2 = fileBaseName + accessionName + "_2_UP" + extName


    fetchCommand = baseCommand + " " + inputFile1 + " " + inputFile2 + " " + outputPFile1 + " " + outputUPF
ile1 + " " + outputPFile2 + " " + outputUPFile2 + " "  + baseParamter

    os.system(fetchCommand)
```

to run the script I did `python3 trimScript_Denovo.py` but keeps returning blank not producing anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you pass arguments when you executed your script via the command line?

Comment: To follow on Pallie's comment above, I think you need to add the accessionNames when calling the script. For your case, it looks to me like it'd be `python3 trimScript_Denovo.py 15013283 15013284`. So the portrayal "my python script name trimScript_Denovo.py" seems at odds with not knowing that? Maybe it is part of learning from a lesson or someone else's code?  You'll want to look into `sys.argv` in relation to calling Python scripts from the command line & passing information in when calling the script.  Looking at `sys.argv` in the `for` loop and the first indented line in the ...

Comment: <continued>  `for` loop, `sys.argv[i]`, is what you'd want to pick up to know from where the script is getting `accessionName` for each round of the `for` loop. The code could have been written to just programmatically mine the number itself from any pair of files that match `SRR<acc_number>_1.fastq1` and `SRR<acc_number>_2.fastq`. Then it would work with just `python3 trimScript_Denovo.py`. You can make that work by first putting in code for scanning the involved directory for files that match the pattern, see Python's `glob` module or `fnmatch` module to understand options for that.